# MVC 4 how to access files out of application virtual directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

MVC 4 C# app, I need to allow users to access files from folders that are out the virtual directory, files are created by another app every month.

1. I do not want user see physical path of files like 
   file1

Could you help to set up access to physical path as virtual path?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can use FilePathResult in MVC.

```
public FilePathResult DownloadFile()
{
   return File(@"C://Test.xlsx","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet","Download File");
}
```

The above solution downloads a Excel file.

Try this and let me know. You can also read the external file in a file stream and use this FilePathResult to return the file.